# Java Restful Web service 404 Error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I am trying to make a RESTFUL JAVA WEB SERVICE using `eclipse` and `maven` in `Apache Tomcat`. Everything seems fine to me and it is not showing any error but when open the URL it shows `404 Error`. 
I am trying to call it via this URL `http://localhost:8080/first/rest`

 **WEB.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
<display-name>first</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>firstapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.first.pkg</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>firstapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>task</groupId>
  <artifactId>first</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>first Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
  </build>
</project>
```

**RestServ.java**

```
package com.first.pkg;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/")
public class RestServ {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response getStartingPage()
    {
        String output = "<h1>Hello World!<h1>" +
                "<p>RESTful Service is running ... <br>Ping @ " + new Date().toString() + "</p<br>";
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<display-name>first</display-name>
```

is a description part and I don't think you can call your web service via this name. Instead, try calling it like

```
http://localhost:8080/{nameOfYourWARFileHere}/rest
```

Also make sure to put `rest` into your `@Path("/")` annotation in RestServ.java right after the slash otherwise the request mapping won't work.

Comment: Make sure you put `@Path("/rest/")` in `RestServ` class as Arthur wrote above